# Mac OSX app not loading URL in Webkit View

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview

I am trying to load a URL inside a Webkit View in a Mac OX app using Swift.

This is how my code looks like right now:

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit
import Foundation
import CoreData
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var rightBox: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftBox: NSView!
    @IBOutlet var myWebView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.wantsLayer = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        leftBox.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
        rightBox.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        myWebView.load(myRequest)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I only see blank white box.
I have tried placing the url loading code both in the viewDidLoad as well as viewWillAppear. Same result.

I am trying to figure out what I might be doing wrong.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have you enabled outgoing connections for your application?

[image: Screen shot showing capabilities panel with Sandbox and outgoing network connections enabled in Xcode]

Had it been an `http://` URL you'd also have to turn on `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in your Info.plist.